# Reference request: The primorial

Tags: reference-request, primorial

The *primorial* function is defined as
$$p_n\#=\prod_{k=1}^{n}p_k$$
where $p_k$ is the $k$th prime (the more general definition is $n\#=\prod_{k=1}^{\pi(n)}p_k$, where $\pi(\cdot)$ is the prime counting function). I can't find much information about this. The [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) gives only some basic facts, of which most of them I can prove myself. I want some more detailed information about it. These types of articles are needed:

- Articles which study primorials as a main goal, rather than studying some other thing, and just giving some info about it at some point.
- I would love any article about it, but the articles that would be the most helpful would be article that study the primality of $p_n\#+1$, and/or the sum $\sum_{p\in\Bbb{P}}\frac{1}{p\#},$ where $\Bbb{P}$ is the set of primes, and/or bounds and asymptotic formulas for primorial.

Comment: For near primorial primes, these OEIS sequences and their links might be of interest: https://oeis.org/A005234, https://oeis.org/A018239, https://oeis.org/A014545, https://oeis.org/A006794.

Comment: Possibly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1594914/655547

Answer (score 0):

The article "Numération primorielle" on wikipédia francophone may interest you.
https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Num%C3%A9ration_primorielle
Concerning the sum S of the inverse of the primorials, it is very interesting to generalize to see what it is about. You can define Primorial expansion of any real(see for example Primorial expansion of e: https://oeis.org/A240472)S=[0,1:1:1:1:1:1:1:....] (using extension of notations stub OEIS concerning Primoradic: https://oeis.org/wiki/Primorial_numeral_system). You may also be interested in [What is the primorial development of e ?(the notion of "primorial development" is defined in the body)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4129454/what-is-the-primorial-development-of-e-the-notion-of-primorial-development-i)